# is a way to set up or by pass authorization for any api in parse server

Tags: parse-platform

how to set parse server API without APPID and master key(without authorization).
i need a one API without authorization.

please let me know if there is a way to set up or by pass authorization for any API in parse server.

Answer (score 0):

You need an App Id and master key in order to use Parse-Server. There is no option to leave those out.

You're able to leave out iOS and Android keys, so that the client *only* needs the app Id and server URL to connect, but this isn't recommended.